# yui get checkbox returns array instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, yui

When getting the checked state of a checkbox with yui `ischecked = this.get('checked');` the `checked` variable returns [true] or [false].

Expected behavior would be a boolean value of true or false rather than have to check for the first (and only) value in the array being true/false.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just figured this out.

We're getting this element with `Y.all()` instead of `Y.one()` (to be null safe). `Y.all()` always returns an array even if it only find one element. Hence the `get()` is returning an array of values.